# I can't seem to [find] a reason for this tag to exist

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The usage guidance is:

> This tag has multiple meanings. Please DO NOT use this tag if you're just trying to find something.

And the description is:

> `find` is:
>
> 1. a filesystem search tool on various flavors of *nix,
> 2. a filesystem search tool on various flavors of DOS and Windows,
> 3. the name of a jQuery method,
> 4. the name of a family of methods in ActiveRecord,
> 5. a function in the C++ standard template library,
> 6. a method of strings in Python,
> 7. a method in many different NoSQL's to find documents in a collection.

So, this seems to be everything and nothing at the same time and it's not really useful to filter for this tag, isn't it?

I also like the usage guidance `Please DO NOT use this tag if you're just trying to find something`, so if I want to find something using `std::find` shall I use the tag or not ;)?

Can someone be an expert in [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find)?

Comment: Even if the tag isn't useful by itself, isn't it useful when another tag is attached e.g. [unix] [find], [jquery] [find], etc.

Comment: @andrewtweber HERESY!

Comment: @andrewtweber: A tag that can only be properly understood with other tags is a chameleon that we don't want: it has no actual meaning on its own. That's a [standard burnination criterion](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) (#4), which this tag appears to fit perfectly.

Comment: The post Nathan linked to also points out that we shouldn't obsess over tags that are not actually causing a problem. This mere existence of this tag is, of course, not a problem. It is perfectly valid to tag a question about `std::find` with [c++] and [find]. Or a question about the jQuery method with [find] and [jquery]. *All* tags are contextual, it is inevitable. That's why we allow 5 of them. This obsession with eliminating "meta" tags is getting ridiculous. The tag system will never be pure, and you wouldn't want it to be. Only "burninate" tags that are problematic.

Comment: @CodyGray A tag whose tag excerpt mainly says when *not* to use the tag is already a problem, to my mind.

Comment: Any tag can have that in its description. Do you think [android] is a good tag? Its description could easily say, *"Do NOT use this tag just because you own an Android device."* The [windows] tag is essential. It could also say, *"Do NOT use this tag just because you are developing on the Windows platform; this tag is for issues related to the Windows operating system."* Probably silly, though, you're right; no one ever follows the advice.

Comment: @CodyGray for the Windows tag all tagged problems have windows in common - what's the common thing of find?

Comment: You are using a tool/API called "find." Same logic as using an operating system named Windows.

Comment: @CodyGray: If there were, in fact, multiple completely unrelated, substantially different operating systems called some variant of "Windows", that would be a serious problem to have that tag. The problem is not that tags can be combined to become more specific; the problem is when a tag has no actual meaning of its own, but rather is a chameleon depending on certain other tags to refer to anything.

Comment: @nathan It is impossible to guarantee that all libraries, functions, etc. will have unique, non-overlapping names. My mention of Windows was not highlighting its ambiguity, but its potential for overuse, thus leading to a prohibition in its excerpt. Irrelevant to the point being made about [find]. Namely, the inevitability of a context-dependent tagging system. The [find] tag has an actual meaning of its own: find. You are using something called find. For more details, read the question and/or look at the other tags. Much ado about nothing. Removing this tag does not provide any benefit.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm having trouble understanding why a tag is of any use here, as opposed to, say, putting it in the question text. Sure, you're using something with the opaque character string "find" as its name. So? What actual *concept* that's more meaningful than "like, dur, finding stuff" does that get across? What unique semantics and constraints does it have? What does this tell us as a tag? Nothing, that's what. [jquery-find] might be useful. [jquery] + [find] sharing nothing of interest with [c++] + [find]... that's an abomination, like unto typing randomly into the tag field.

Comment: @nathan It describes the question, the whole point of a tag system. I feel like you are being intentionally obtuse here. It is inappropriate to use a find tag when the question is about "dur finding stuff." Perfectly valid when you're using a library function or a tool with the specific name "find." Like [locale] (crap, plz don't burninate that). I don't know why you think tag prefixes are useful. A [jquery-find] tag offers absolutely nothing that [jquery]+[find] doesn't already give us. This is the whole point of allowing multiple tags. If we could only use one, we'd need compound tags.

Comment: @CodyGray: You'll have to go beyond the simplistic "describes the question" approach. That's wholly inadequate, as years of experience fixing tag-derp-spews has shown us. ("What do you mean I can't just copy-paste my title into the tag field?") As a first approximation, tags are a *structured* way to describe *certain useful parts* of the question with *cross-cutting, peer-curated, specific concepts* that are more than simply words that happen to be in the question, or even words that are important to the question. Please do not discard years of hard-earned fine distinctions.

Comment: @nathan It is slightly ironic that you have been a member far less time than I have, and yet you're telling me about all this unique experience you have with how tags are supposed to work. Sure, all of that is true, I agree with all the buzzwords. I also agree that putting nonsense or sentences into the tag field doesn't work. I've fixed thousands of these mistagged questions. I'm not sure how you're missing the fact that words like "find," "locale," "array," and "font" are *useful parts* of the question, essential for categorizing it, even if they happen to have multiple meanings.

Comment: @CodyGray: While it might be nice to have a more specific breakdown of [font] (woff, ttf, otf, etc), there's a fairly limited set of standards, and most platforms have to deal with more than one, so it's basically "here's the entire set of possibilities". But [find] is unbounded. [array] is likewise less than ideal, but there are certain key unchanging aspects that are features of anything you can usually call an "array", and by fiat anything that doesn't match that can be called something different. But [find] has, as far as I know, no such features.

Comment: @CodyGray: [locale] is sketchier; I'm having trouble understanding what that buys anyone that the very high-level [localization] tag doesn't get (which would, admittedly, probably do better as a tag on ProgSE). It's not as though there's all that much commonality between locale APIs on different platforms, except for international standards... but then using tags for the standards is far more interesting. [find] has, of course, no standard that applies to all or even most of its stuff.

Comment: You have to be smarter than a dictionary. It helps to know something about the language and/or APIs involved. Locale, for example, is a facility provided by the C++ standard library. The tag is *not* a synonym of "localization."

Comment: @CodyGray: So [locale] is in the same boat as [find], then: there's multiple concepts related only by a general purpose, not any technical commonality worth discussing. (By the way, while I recognize your long history on SO and MSO, almost anyone can get suckered by the weird subtleties of tags if they start thinking things are simpler than they are. That's why discarding what little we have managed to work out so far is unwise.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy tl;dr: tags aren't hashtags :D

Answer (score 1):

This is an old request, but I think that we should burninate this tag. As its tag Wiki shows, this is far too ambiguous to be much use. Several of the listed meanings aren't even on-topic; filesystem search tools are about general computing, not programming.