# Could we stop with all those "burnination" requests?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

Every day it is the same thing: everyone keeps viewing on SO a link to one of those "burnination" requests within the "hot meta posts" area.

Every time with a supposedly funny pun in the title.

Every time to dig up an old unused tag that causes absolutely no harm to anyone.

I'm really under the impression 90% of the time people only do this to have their own meta post with tons of upvotes. That they waste like an hour only to find an harmless tag and an associated pun.

The official guideline about [when to "burninate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191) is pretty clear:

> If you're thinking that these criteria are gonna be pretty tedious to
>   evaluate on a tag with thousands of questions in it, then you're
>   absolutely right - which is why I'm pretty skeptical toward a lot of
>   these requests on those rare occasions I take time to do it. If you're
>   thinking that it's not worth the effort for tags that generally don't
>   seem to be causing any problems, then you're sharper than half the
>   folks throwing up these requests. If it looks like pointless busywork,
>   it probably is pointless busywork...

So what is the point of this massive waste of time for everyone? Could we stop this?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you think this practice would be more tolerable without the funny puns or are you against the practice in general?

Comment: Also, if you don't want to do it, why not just add the tag to your ignore list and stop worrying about it? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Also I'm suspicious of your *"Every. single. day."* claim given that none of the four Hot Meta Posts I can currently see are burninations.

Comment: I suspect the votes this question gets will show evidence that nothing can be done to stop it.  Well, yay for giving it a shot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I and others downvoted the last one (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318316/lets-burninate-our-finance) so it's not on the main page anymore

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Without the "funny" puns, no one would care and no one would waste time on this. It wouldn't be more "tolerable", it's just one could hope only useful requests would be submitted.

Comment: @ken2k frankly that's the least relevant part of my comment - could you have a go at the rest of it? What is the *problem?* Is it that you think the time spent on burninating would be better spent on something else (what? And would people actually spend time on it if they weren't burninating)? Is it that you think people shouldn't get upvotes on Meta (and, given that they don't count for anything, how could you possibly care)? Is it that you just don't like puns? Is there some harm being caused by this (if the tags being there is harmless, what's the problem with them not being there)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought it was clear in my post, the problem is the waste of time for everyone: people that write those requests, people that review those requests, people (moderators) that delete/merge all those unused harmless tags. I'm against this massive waste of time/energy/effort. There are lots of others issues on SO that should be addressed first.

Comment: Aside from the moderators (which is a tiny part of the time involved), that's all time that those people are apparently willing to spend. Again, anyone is welcome to ignore the requests completely if they aren't interested. And rather than complaining about burninations, why not write something about these *"lots of other issues"*?

Comment: @jon You have to constantly be vigilant, posting a reasoned defense of tags that you like, otherwise they are in danger of being termed "too broad" or having some other hand-wavy problem and burninated by bored folks. I tire of this. **Burnination requests are fine, they just need to defend why the tag's presence is harmful.** Otherwise, they're just a waste of everyone's time. The argument you are basically making (if some people want to waste their time, who cares?) is incorrect. It wastes my time having to defend tags and having retagged questions cluttering up my homepage.

Comment: @CodyGray *"The argument you are basically making (if some people want to waste their time, who cares?) is incorrect."* - fair enough, but that's the sort of thing that should be in the question! Just asserting that it's a waste of time helps nobody understand what the problem is.

Comment: Why do YOU think you can dictate what unpaid volunteers spend their time on? Btw @CodyGray According to the burnination rules almost any tag fits the definition of one that can be burninated if enough people agree.

Comment: @Magisch, depends on the impact this has on other unpaid volunteers. Remember freedom ends where another one's nose begins. If there is a problem here, we may as well discuss it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi A successful argument for burnination according to the rules is already "I think this tag adds nothing of value, so make it go away" if enough people agree, thats it, tag gone.

Comment: @Magish, yes, I do agree with that. However, it appears that this practice impacts negatively at least one user, maybe more. I'm not much into retagging myself, and I don't feel impacted, but maybe we could devise a way to do it that is less annoying to users who agree with the questioner.

Comment: I think @Cody nailed it pretty well, ought to be in the question.  The problem is that people just go ahead without getting a consensus, enough votes on the question is enough.  You *have* to speak up if you disagree to have any shot at slowing them down, very tiresome.  That makes the puns especially annoying because that draws upvotes for the pun, not for the request.  Makes it too hard to counter with a reasoned answer.  It is rather a slimy approach to getting a perceived okay.

Comment: @Magisch - "almost any tag fits the definition of one that can be burninated if enough people agree." - utter rubbish. You'd have to live on meta 24x7 to catch every tag "burnination", I don't have time for that, I also don't have to time to micro-defend on several different fronts the illogical group-think of a few determined individuals. There needs to be a far better consensus mechanism for some of the tag upheaval I've seen over the years.

Comment: I'd also love to see these burnination posts hidden from the "Hot Meta Posts" sidebox.

Comment: Who in their right mind would support burning a tag with 1000s of posts?

Comment: "I'm really under the impression 90% of the time people only do this to have their own meta post with tons of upvotes." Data? Otherwise, your impression == your issue, not ours.

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW I do. [internet had +1.7k questions when it was deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255169/792066)

Comment: "Every day it is the same thing:" clueless users coming up with worse and worse new tags, renaming new ones and defining meaningless ones.

Comment: I really wish the title left out the absurd over-dramatic "witch hunt" rhetoric. Tags are not people. If we burn them, who cares. They're there to serve us, not to be coddled, so any reason not to burn tags is not because they deserve special consideration, but because they are not useless enough to warrant the effort of burning.

Comment: You can forget that users stop posting these requests and given the fact that I also believe those posts need exposure on main to get non-meta attention you'll keep seeing them. What I can try with the SOCVR room is to actively monitor those posts and make sure those posts are sane so you know they make sense when they turn hot or featured. That is the least I can so with the time I'm wasting.

Comment: @Braiam good call, I deleted my comment.

Comment: Some good points in this question. Unfortunately it is quite biased and forgets to mention all the good points about tag moderation. The same could be said for questions and editing. Every day, answered questions are edited. Every single day. And people only do it to get tons of upvotes. It's a massive waste of time. Can we stop this? :)

Answer (score 11):

This is a massive problem, in my opinion. There are several major issues:

1. **Every time a "burnination" request comes up, it has to be dealt with.** Well, that much is obvious, but it has a number of hidden consequences. It requires a bunch of meta discussion, requiring members of the community to give up on answering questions while they engage in a defense or betrayal of the tag in question. If you are not ever-vigilant (sometimes my life gets in the way, for example, and I don't have time to visit the site every day), you run the risk of a tag you considered important being burninated.

   It is a Meta-elitist game. (I can say that because I *am* one of the Meta elitists.) The problem is that most of the active users on the site are not necessarily Meta participants. If they fail to come and defend their tag (either because of ignorance or apathy or time constraints), the burnination request will probably still build up apparently sufficient mass because of the Meta-elitist crowd. This speaks directly to Magisch's claim that

   > A successful argument for burnination according to the rules is already "I think this tag adds nothing of value, so make it go away" if enough people agree, thats it, tag gone.

   No, in fact, the silence of voices tells us nothing absent a guarantee that the opposition will speak. If you rile up the entire Meta army, you can create a situation where there *appears* to be consensus behind the burnination of the tag, but there really isn't. This is not just my opinion. At least half of the recent burnination requests have been highly contentious, accumulating a number of downvotes (Meta-speak for "I disagree"). These too often get ignored.

   Now, granted, it's not like you'll wake up one day and find the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag gone. The burninators haven't gone that far yet, and I'm sure that they will not. They certainly mean well. The target of their ire is tags with relatively more obscure meanings. However, they suffer from a lack of imagination. Lacking domain-relevant knowledge about what the tag might mean and how it could be appropriately used, they fall back on the defense that a simple familiarity with the principles of the tagging system is sufficient. Which brings us to…
2. **There exists fundamental disagreement about which tags are acceptable and which are unacceptable.** I could go on and on about this, but it is not especially productive. The point is simply that the disagreement exists.

   We could perhaps divide the perspectives into two camps. On the one side are the purists, who think that the tag system should be as pure as possible. They strive to stamp out ambiguous tags, those with overlapping and unclear meanings, and if they are not careful, those that they personally find uninteresting or not useful. On the other side are the pragmatists, who accept that any tag system will necessarily be impure, and instead focus on making it as useful as possible for categorizing and identifying questions.

   I'll pick on him here because [I recently had this discussion with Nathan Tuggy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318232/366904). At issue are the tags [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find) and [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locale). Both admittedly have "overloaded" meanings—does that make them bad tags? Do they need to be burninated? It is time to embrace the reality that the English language will never be as purely hierarchized as some programmers might wish. We need to realize and embrace the limitations of our own classificatory system.

   Another recent example is the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)/[cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade)/[css-cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-cascade) [debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318238/should-cascade-be-used-for-css-or-better-retag-to-css-cascade). The purists appear to favor "compound" tags (like [css-cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-cascade)) because they abhor the possibility of a generic tag like [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade) having multiple meanings. I argue pragmatically that context is necessary in a good tagging system (the system even admits this by allowing up to 5 tags on a single question). I don't see the point in having a "css-" prefix when you can just tag the question with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade). If you don't like CSS questions, you can filter those tagged [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) out. Do we really need [c-locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-locale), [c++-locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-locale), [java-locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-locale), *ad nauseum*?

   Anyway, rather than having this discussion on *each* burnination request, we need to have it in general. Contrary to the insistence of Nathan, I do not believe that this is a settled issue.
3. **The obsessive focus on burnination is a waste of time.** The argument has been made that it only wastes the time of people who wish to spend it on this, but that is specious for several reasons. First, as has been shown above, burnination requests require (nay, *demand*) the engagement of the entire community. It cannot possibly be something that concerns only those interested in pursuing it.

   Second, people who are devoted enough to improving the site that they would spend their time burninating tags would also be willing to do *other* things to help improve the site. I think this is the clencher. Of all the major issues confronting Stack Overflow, a few ambiguous, unclear, less-useful-than-they-could-possibly be tags are not among them. We are overflowing with poor-quality questions that need to be cleaned up—downvoted, closed, and deleted. The number of new questions outnumbers the people willing and able to answer them by an order of magnitude. Personally, I don't think we have enough tools right now to be able to deal with this epic level of crap, but whether you agree with that or not, *this* is the real problem that we need to be focusing on.

   Now, there are certain cases where bad tags are contributing to the crap. A hypothetical [careers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/careers) tag might need to be burninated if it was causing people to think that they could post blatantly off-topic questions. This is a *productive* use of our time because burninating that tag would be cutting off the problem at its source, rather than having to deal piecemeal with each off-topic question. This is why I am not categorically opposed to tag burnination. I just think we need some *sanity*. Shog9 seems to think the same thing:

   > If you're thinking that these criteria are gonna be pretty tedious to evaluate on a tag with thousands of questions in it, then *you're absolutely right* - which is why I'm pretty skeptical toward a lot of these requests on those rare occasions I take time to do it. If you're thinking that it's not worth the effort for tags that generally don't seem to be causing any problems, **then you're sharper than half the folks throwing up these requests.** If it *looks* like pointless busywork, it probably *is* pointless busywork...

   Although the burnination crusaders love to link to his burnination criteria (which is certainly a positive development), they keep ignoring that paragraph. And, therefore, losing sight of the big picture. Burnination requests are fine, so long as you provide and can defend a justification for why the tag is actively causing harm. If you cannot, it is a waste of time, energy, and effort.
4. Procedurally, **the process of burnination actively interferes with my (and other users') ability to use the site.** I rely principally on the personalized homepage (seeded with recently active questions from my favorite tags) to find questions that I want to answer. This means that when a tag is in the process of being burninated, a denial-of-service attack is effectively launched on my homepage. This has been happening a lot recently. Previously inactive questions get bumped up by a silly edit to remove a harmless tag. Yet, there is nothing new or interesting about these questions. They do not need my attention. Unfortunately, they quickly fill up my homepage, bumping off the questions that *do* deserve my attention. This makes it harder for me to find questions to answer and less fun because I have to wade through a bunch of uninteresting garbage. Not to put too fine a point on this, but in several recent cases, the process of burnination has *actively interfered* with my ability to use the site in my most valuable capacity: as an expert who can provide answers to questions.

   I place this reason last because one could make a reasonable argument that this is not a reason to stop burninating problematic tags altogether, but simply a flaw with the current implementation of the system. Although that is true, this *is* a problem in the status quo and its significance cannot be underestimated. Until we can fix the process to minimize this side-effect, we need to minimize the frequency with which we run the process.

Comment: You're missing an additional point in the burnination process: it is also a chance to go clean up old off-topic questions. So it is also helpful in that way. Hence it is not a complete waste of time. Also, #4 has been adressed in a Meta post where it was requested that tag edits do not bump the post (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310787/1743880) sadly without too much attention.

Comment: They are developing policy for burniation.. I will grab you  some links

Comment: No, no. I've seen their policies. I've been told countless times how it builds on Shog9's criteria. I keep pointing out the quoted paragraph above, and it keeps getting ignored because...policy! Aside from that, the policy fails to (1) establish community consensus and (2) solve point #4.

Comment: Actually the policies are pretty [clear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) if a tag fits any of the descriptions (meta tag, not unambiguous, etc) then it can be burninated. Wether or not it is depends on a few votes on meta and tag size, and nothing more. This has been per-se practice for quite some times now. If you want to argue against that I suggest you take that to MSE and make an argument on that post or raise a new post about that.

Comment: Sonofabitch am I the only one here who can't read? It pretty clearly says, paraphrased: "Here are the criteria: 1, 2, 3, 4. But it's not worth the effort for tags that generally don't seem to be causing any problems." Only in those cases where "tags get in the way, add confusion, start fights, take the place of *better* tags" are you supposed to raise the matter for discussion on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray And even one person arguing its noise is enough to satisfy that if enough people agree.

Comment: Oh, ***fantastic***. One person controls the direction of policy. No, that is irrevocably broken. And *guaranteed* not to be what Shog meant.

Comment: @Kev Thats not how this works. Everyone has a voice here, and just because I happen to dissent (alot) doesn't mean mine is invalid because of my joining date. Facts don't respect rep or joining date, and I have yet to see factual arguments against the applicability of the (community and SE staff consensus) rule post I linked.

Comment: The decision to not allow meta and unambigous tags has been made a while ago, and it has been made somewhere else. You guys are definately barking up the wrong tree, here.

Comment: I was there for all of that, @Magisch. I participated in many of those discussions, and certainly read all of them. When we prohibited "meta-tags," we had in mind tags like [homework], [best-practices], [subjective], [beginner], [programming], [fun], [computing], and so on. These are all *real examples* pulled from Jeff's blog post and Meta.SE. So you are either misinterpreting or disagreeing with the interpretation of what a meta tag is. When the consensus formed against meta tags, we were not imagining that it would exclude [locale] or [finance] or [cascade].

Comment: @CodyGray Meta tag: A tag that couldn't be the question's only tag". Yes I am aware that that means that basicly everything besides the language tags is up for burning at some point or another.

Comment: If you want to split it in two groups, it's not purists and pragmatists, but purists and inclusionists. Pragmatists try to find a pragmatic middle ground between being too pure to be usable, and so woolly as to be useless.

Comment: I agree with some parts of this answer, and disagree with others, so +1/-1 = no vote from me.

Comment: The **defining** characteristic of a meta tag is not that it cannot stand alone, @Magisch, it's that [it describes the _question_, not the _subject of the question_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273082/603977).

Comment: "people who are devoted enough to improving the site that they would spend their time burninating tags would also be willing to do other things to help improve the site." This skirts the 'fallacy of relative privation', since votes of all kinds have daily limits, while tag edits do not. It's also not necessarily true that those who are able to edit tags are also able to do things like close and delete low-quality stuff. However, the final point in this paragraph is well-taken: the energy put into burnination could be put into things like userscripts to facilitate other kinds of moderation.

Comment: Point number 2 suggests that a constructive "step 0" should be added to the "burnination procedure", that of soliciting clarifying edits to the tag's usage guidelines. Unfortunately, that contradicts your point 1, which is a more important point.

Comment: As for the bumping of questions: When the SOCVR room is heading the effort we could refrain from re-tagging for those posts we know the tag can be removed at the end. It then becomes a CM action and doesn't cause bumps. It makes it maybe a little bit harder for us to track progress. But I'll keep wasting my time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with all the burnination requests I see on the site, and I do agree there's too many. The best way to prevent people from wasting time like this and to prevent the tag's burnination is to use votes and post an answer arguing against.

I have made one burnination request [Do we need the [checklist] tag. If so, what is it about?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316057/do-we-need-the-checklist-tag-if-so-what-is-it-about). The tag was so mixed, it was unclear what it was supposed to represent.

There were 40 upvotes, 5 downvotes on the question. I used no humour in the question and sought advice from an experienced user, [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene), and the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) about how we proceeded. I was told that there was a group of people working out a [burnination protocol](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md) to prevent people from stampeding into burninations.

Whether people work on moderating the site or contributing or both, there's no reason to slam people who genuinely attempt to help the site.

Wading in with accusations and insults, only serves to alienate people.

> I'm really under the impression 90% of the time people only do this to have their own meta post with tons of upvotes. That they waste like an hour only to find an harmless tag and an associated pun.

From my comments there can be discrepancy with voting on Meta and the usefulness of the post. People too often vote for personalities, or humour, rather than principles. Over time I have noticed the Meta culture has changed a lot, but it still has a social feel to it.

If people do not like the direction a community driven site is taking, the best way to combat that is to be active within the Meta community.

Yes all societies are held together by its members, but it's the political drive that determines the direction of a community. In a democracy, there are politicians voted in by the community or in this case, the `popular vote on meta == political drive`. If you have an interest in where the community is headed, be active in the meta processes of that community.

If the tone of the question had been less afronting, it would have been a good question to have on the site to actually address the issue of unwarranted burnination requests.

Comment: *"There's no point complaining about it and criticizing people for being active on meta and from a lofty height claiming to be too busy"* - fine, but have a proper vote with a closing date. Not the current situ where 10-15 upvotes take place within 2hrs which is then interpreted as the community agreeing. Hell, I've seen useful/non-egregious tags disappear in the space of a meeting or long lunch. That's not exactly democratic.

Comment: @Kev I've not disagreed with that. I have not done that myself and it's no ones place to run off and burn tags without a community consensus.. It also requires support to do so. The whole process involves closing off topic posts, as a truly burnable tag usually contains a lot of poor quality posts.. anyway see my edit, added a link. I removed the crappy part of my post, it was rude.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I reckon that tag burnination require massive spendings of time, but I also reckon that that time well spent.

What you are saying is akin to telling the janitor of a school to stop cleaning the building, since it's already *so clean*, and start teaching children. It's simply a leap logic. The building is clean because the janitor is doing its job, that you don't see it or appreciate it doesn't make the janitorial work any less important nor unnecessary. There are tags that needs to be burned, and these people are using their time in what they believe is more effective use of *their* time, that unlike the janitor, is not paid upfront in a tangential way.

Now, why are tag burnination so important, you may ask yourself (or not)? Tags are the most basic way of bringing order to the mess of [new questions that are asked every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). Why is that order needed? Because without it, the questions will not meet the people that can either answer it or close it. **That's the main goal of the tags.** And this goal is intimately linked to the purpose of burninations.

You may think "that's crazy", well, it isn't. Remember when you read the "how to ask" page? You only need one tag to ask your question, and if that *one tag* isn't the correct tag, your question will be left unanswered for all eternity (or until someone asks the same question but with the correct tag, and this time you will really do your homework, dammit). Isn't this sad? A single mistake and your problem will not be solved. The thing is, that most people don't even understand this greater goal, which is what makes tags so damn hot.

So now that you know the value of a single tag, what has to do with burninations? Well, if the only tags that remains are the ones that can and will get your questions answered (or closed), that bit of attention, we become more effective and efficient at answering questions overall, and the people that abhor tag burninations so much didn't even had to move a finger to obtain that.

Comment: Having both attended and worked in a school, I can confidently say that janitors do not come into the classroom and clean it while people are trying to teach/learn. The reason they don't do that is it is disruptive. Burnination is equally disruptive. Furthermore, when janitors get overzealous with their cleaning (like when they erase information from boards or throw away student projects), it poses a problem and they are asked to stop. They stick with vacuuming the floor and emptying the trashcans because these are non-contentious and everyone agrees they should be done.

Comment: Finally, janitors are not certified teachers, so they could not be better spending their time teaching. However, the people doing the burnination are obviously experts in something, having earned sufficient rep to do edits, so they could be contributing that knowledge to the site's body of knowledge. Or they could be cleaning up the really visible garbage, the bad questions that plague the site. I disagree with your implication that the existence of the tags recently called to be burninated are the source of this garbage. If that were true, I would support their burnination.

Comment: Why can't a janitor be a teacher?

Comment: @CodyGray well, have you seen any of those janitors barging in your classroom while you are teaching? I assure you that when they do, they have very good reason to do so.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure if you are commenting to my post or to Cody's comments?

Comment: It is a comment towards *Finally, janitors are not certified teachers*

Comment: @Nathan They *could* be, but they generally *are not*. Division of labor and all that. Teachers make more money than janitors because they have more education and a higher level of skill. I'm not trying to disparage anyone here, and certainly teachers can and should pick up their own trash. But no one really thinks teachers should mop the hallways between classes. That's Braiam's point. Mine is that janitors work in the background, trying their best not to disrupt the *main* purpose of a school: learning.

Comment: Braiam, I have had janitors barge into my classroom. Multiple times. They were just too lazy to look in the window and notice class was in session. They went merely by the clock, and since it was after the official dismissal time, they turned off their brain. If they're just emptying the trashcan in all the classrooms on the hall, I let them do it. It was minimally disruptive and needed to be done. If they were coming in with a vacuum cleaner, I pointed to the door. I can't teach over a vacuum cleaner. This is the point, most burnination requests aren't dealing with serious problems.

Comment: @CodyGray if you have a lump of crap in the middle of the salon, you will stop the janitor with the vacuum cleaner, because is disruptive? Sorry, but your classroom was already disrupted as is. The janitor is just doing his job.

Comment: Tags are not themselves lumps of crap, @Braiam: they're the labels on the classroom door.

Comment: @JoshCaswell what kind of crappy leap logic are you trying to put on my mouth?

Comment: Your whole answer argues that tag burnination is important janitorial work. Cody Gray says that it's disruptive. [You made the analogy to a lump of crap](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318426/could-we-stop-with-all-those-burnination-witch-hunts/318436?noredirect=1#comment318358_318436) in the middle of the classroom and its being disruptive already, and I'm saying that your analogy is invalid because a tag is not like a lump of crap in the middle of the classrom. I'm not putting any words in your mouth.

Comment: @JoshCaswell of course you are, because you are saying that I said that tags = crap. I've never said that **" Because without it, the questions will not meet the people that can either answer it or close it. That's the main goal of the tags. And this goal is intimately linked to the purpose of burninations."** Read the post instead of making assumptions on your own.

Answer (score -20):

I agree with you, and am [against deletionist practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316066/should-all-burninate-requests-follow-a-template) in general. However, I rarely visit Stack Overflow, those with too much time on their hands and too little inclination to do real answering and/or curation of content will inevitably fill the void.

Bottom line: it's people like me who are to blame for harmful burnination requests rising to the top.

> *The world is in greater peril from those who tolerate or encourage evil than from those who actually commit it.*
>
> **Albert Einstein**

P.S. Yes, we've seen it all before - on Wikipedia. The trend is similar because the underlying social dynamics are the same.

Comment: So, editing tags so the right people see the questions they are able to answer isn't curation?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. How are you responsible for these burnination requests just because you rarely visit the site?

Comment: @Braiam - it is, when done judiciously and on a case-by-case basis. I disagree with blind deletion of content by people who know nothing about the tag and the concepts behind it.

Comment: @CodyGray - 'The world is in greater peril from those who tolerate or encourage evil than from those who actually commit it'.

Comment: @DeerHunter so unless everyone who could possibly ever have known anything about a tag agrees, it shouldnt be burninated? No, obviously not. Your argument is a non-sequitur.