# Do we need coordinated efforts to moderate the site?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderation, vote-to-delete, moderator-abilities

A Background Example:

I have been participating in the Godaddy Burnination [Should we burninate [godaddy]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/please-help-out-with-burninating-godaddy)

A request I did not want.

[image]

Yet I have assisted with this daily, am even a room owner of the [chat room dedicated to the process](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120759/godaddy-burnination) and continue to cast delete votes on the closed posts that remain on the site.

This is what we have done so far:

[image]
<sub>image courtesy of [Tunaki's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) bot [Burnaki](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32533653#32533653)</sub>

Closed over 1300 posts with the tag.

[A look at my edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/yvette?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1) will show I have removed the tag on questions where I thought they would remain on topic without the tag.

As one person I have reviewed as best I can and I am fallible. Indeed we all are fallible.

Now why did/do I bother to help with this burnination process I didn't want?

Because I knew it was a large task and that the people trying to do it needed all the help they could get. Although it was not my vote to delete the tag it was the community's wish and so my opinion really did not matter. The burnination would continue whether I assisted or not.

Why did I care?

I care about the site and the people who care about the site.

However, what I am tired of are people getting so upset with people who put effort and *volunteer* their time to help moderate the site.

I am mindfully choosing to not link specific posts and comments here to provide evidence that people who choose to close and delete posts do not regularly come under criticism,

But a search for [why + closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why%20closed) yields 1488 results and a search for
[why + deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why%20deleted) 1725 results. Invariably within these results there will be some complaint issued towards to the users of the site who are "so quick to close questions" and who "don't contribute to the site" aka "not answering questions.

But maybe I am misguided and we are too intrusive into the site, armed with our votes and flags.

Off the top of my head I can list 6 chatrooms, that exist only to coordinate user efforts to assist with moderating the site:

[socvr](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), [socvfinder](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/socvfinder), [godaddy burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120759/godaddy-burnination), [campaigns](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns), [room to catch old off topic questions with link only answers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121786/discussion-on-answer-by-shog9-how-many-old-accepted-high-score-link-only-answe), [charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq).

So my question to the community is this:

There are many groups of users who make coordinated efforts to moderate the site.

What good (if any) do these groups really achieve for the site? Are they more problem than help?

And so, we now have a post for people to air how they feel about this issue.

Comment: I'm sure this question can be improved. Godaddy is an example, that the mod efforts are not always something we enjoy. But something we do as an attempt to help. If you think an edit can improve this please feel free to do so

Comment: *A request I did not want.* ...wait ... what ... I wouldn't personally volunteer my time for things I don't want to so. Am I mis interpreting that sentence?

Comment: @rene I didn't agree with that burnination, I thought the tag was useful, but as it was clear (by 300+ votes) that it was going, of course I was going to help you guys. It's a lot of hard work! So what I am saying is, I try to act in the best interest of the site, as the community sees it, not just on my own opinion. This is tag burnination, not euthanasia ;)

Comment: As a courtesy, I've let the chat rooms know there is a linked meta post, as I do not represent these rooms.

Comment: 60+ posts in [meta-tag:clean-up] tag over here spanning 5 last years seem to suggest that efforts coordination is popular and generally welcome

Comment: @gnat care to use this as a basis for an answer? ;)

Comment: @Yvette I will hardly have time to cover this topic as much as it deserves, there is just too much in there. 60+ posts I referred are just tip of the iceberg, there are also almost 100 posts in [clean-up tag at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-up), and [Posse Comitatus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139087/165773) room with rich and fruitful history. And I don't even dare to dive into cleanup efforts at other sites...

Comment: @gnat I posted this, as there are many snarly remarks made at people making a concerted mod effort and I thought it would be good to allow detractors a chance to fully air grievances and also to have a canonical post to link to future comments.

Comment: I understand that and that's why I am hesitant to write an answer. In some pass-by minor meta discussion I'd drop these few lines and be done with it, but this deserves a much more solid [meta-tag:canonical] answer, I just don't have time for it now

Comment: I know we can close 150 to 180 java questions some days. Then we get a little bored and give it up for a few days

Comment: Give yourself a little more credit now and then. The community voting overwhelmingly to clobber godaddy then ran with its tail between its legs while few people actually closed (I pretty much didn't do anything). Mainly because I didn't believe in this one. But you stepped up. What, 20 hours of work, 10? Don't take crap from people that don't lift a finger

Comment: As far as your link above 2 lines up, I just think you are temporarily burn out and frustrated. So take a little time off imo.

Comment: as far as I can tell in that clobbered answer you have lost in a simple meta game. I know it can be painful, I myself am losing at least 2/3 such games (although as you play more of these, pain of losing may decrease, as it happened to me). The game is, when someone posts a "potential hit" comment under your post, you have to _very quickly_ reply to it with even stronger comment (sometimes you have to additionally edit the post, but comment still should go first and fast) and if you don't then post drowns in downvotes...

Comment: ...such a counter-tactics requires too much effort and because of that I use it very sparingly, only on posts I consider super important or when I have enough free time and simply wish to entertain myself and test if I am fast enough to play it

Comment: I just want to say, I hate burnination requests and am not helping with another one. They're exhausting. I'm going to vote on crap that comes onto the front page of the site, or has been recently bumped. All else can remain invisible and forgotten, whether or not it remains useful.

Answer (score 31):

http://media.btp.police.uk/services/GetImage.ashx?id=1vqxyoLa976Zo5vFx%2FH5qw%3D%3D&thumbnailsize=-1&download=1&doctype=0

Community self-moderation, by the British Transport Police.

Every now and then, in the paper on my morning commute, I see a story about how a group of commuters tackled a mugger and held them until the police arrived, whereupon the miscreant was apprehended and everyone lived happily ever after.

Sort of like *group moderation*.

What would happen if *one* commuter at a time tried to tackle the mugger, while everyone else watched? It'd take much longer to deal with the problem, wouldn't it? The mugger - in this case [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) - would have a chance of getting away, and causing more problems.

If instead a group, like SOCVR, throw themselves simultaneously and heroically upon the dastardly criminal, winning both the distressed damsel's handbag and the affection of the nation (yeah, right), what chance does [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) the mugger have?

---

Group moderation is more effective than moderation alone. While the metaphors of police, tag-muggers and damsels' handbags don't *quite* translate to SO, they're not far off. Group moderation is worth doing - but here's the killer - **as long as it's done correctly.**

Sure, mistakes are acceptable here and there, but the group need to make sure it's consistent, generally accurate, and that it doesn't gradually become short-sighted to its original laudable goals. Terse comments, just because this is the twenty-ninth gimme-teh-codez post you've reviewed today, don't help moderation and aren't acceptable. (I'm not directing this at anyone in particular; it's a general caution.)

And if people get upset about your mistakes - welcome to moderation, kids. This is what you signed up for.

Now, if you'll excuse me, I've a mugger to catch.

Comment: Wish I could +10 this

Comment: "Group moderation is more effective than moderation alone." I think while this is true you probably overestimate the benefit. After all users in a group don't have more time magically. It would be nice to try to quantify the benefits of group moderation. After all the close vote review queue is already kind of group moderation. Can you really get much, much better?

Comment: "And if people get upset about your mistakes ..." Maybe people get more upset about correlations in mistakes than about single uncorrelated mistakes. They could feel like being targeted by a group. Solution would probably be if you behaved like not being part of a group while being part of a group. Kind of trusting in your own internal compass most.

Answer (score 28):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote):

> Our sites are all intended to be a sort of representative democracy.

That means if the community decides (e.g. through upvoting a burnination request) that some 'injustice' has been done to the site, it must be repaired. If it can be solved by a single user on their own (e.g. if the number of affected questions is small), that's fine, but even for a small task, coordinated effort helps

1. when multiple users are required (e.g. to cast close votes)
2. if for some questions/answers it isn't immediately clear if they should be cleaned up or not.
3. by double-checking the actions by another user of the group (I don't think this happens every time, though)

---

> Invariably within these results there will be some complaint issued towards to the users of the site who are "so quick to close questions" and who "don't contribute to the site" aka "not answering questions.

Within a representative democracy, you are bound to expect people who feel bad about the community's decisions. Meta Stack Overflow acts as some kind of board where you can appeal to a decision by the community. As long as you do this in a respectful fashion, I don't see the problem - there are enough qualified users here who can explain the reasons behind the decision.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you. I don't want to accept any answer just now, so people feel they can contribute. An accepted answer discourages more answers.

Comment: @Yvette thanks (also for posting the question). I think it can be a very interesting discussion, I'm interested to hear from other people as well. Especially the arguments against coordinated efforts.

Answer (score 20):

Yes!, to coordinated efforts to moderate the site!, this is the only way to handle certain tasks that otherwise seems hopeless to single users.

**but**

The people leading the task needs to make sure the coordination is within limits of what is allowed on SO (no targeting individual users etc), keeping actions and discussion public on meta and/or in chat rooms.

**and**

Every user participating in the coordinated effort, must make his/her own decision as the individual needs to respond why action was taken.

---

> The frustration " I am tired of are people getting so upset with people who put effort and volunteer their time to help moderate the site"

Yeah I also feel this frustration when I see certain comments on meta etc, with the instinct to respond

***"Hey, You go and review 500 questions and then I will find something you probably did wrong."***

but then my mind settles and it's obvious that any user have the right to question the effort. In the case of [godaddy] except for some non-constructive comments, I believe that the OP was correct to post on meta to ask why question was closed and/or deleted. In the specific case the OP also seemed very reasonable as I have seen other users asking in comments why their post was [targeted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882329/urlrewriter-net-with-net-4-0-not-working#comment65448959_4882329), but if meet with helpful information later [join the effort](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32413167#32413167)

> Solution to the frustration

1. Ignore any "non-constructive" meta comments (I flag them just to have the pleasure of seeing them denied) and put your self in the mind set of the OP that is asking, if you still have energy; answer why you took the decision otherwise just move on to something with more fun.
2. If frustration still grows, do not take part of the effort in the end you need some amusement since you are not getting paid.

<sup>Discloser: I'm one of the founders and RO of [SOCVFinder](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/socvfinder) room.</sup>

Comment: This post looks lonely without a comment, so here's comment. ;)

Comment: That's the kind of amusement we need, thanks

Comment: Loving the new pic ;) Is that you?

Comment: Yeah, it is : ) at Elba

Comment: @Yvette We will get tons of TC flags on these comments : )

Comment: Let them try, as if meta is not one big chat fest ;) we can always go to ... *chat*

Answer (score 14):

My biggest concern with this is, while the effort(s) are often well-intentioned and ultimately beneficial for the site, group-coordinated moderation will tend to lead to a lot of groupthink on content that deserves more time and care.  That is to say, it makes one participating in this sort of activity prone to going on "autopilot"; helping others either close or delete a question without really looking at it.

To some participants' credit, they have been called out on this and have corrected their actions, but given that certain moderation moves like deletion are such a heavy blow, having any kind of autopilot without considering all sides to a question is a dangerous precedent to set.

I won't say that there aren't some bad questions that efforts like this have gotten rid of; for that, I feel like these things are worth it.  The problem is the questions that stand a chance, yet are often trampled underneath such efforts.

In regards to this:

> However, what I am tired of are people getting so upset with people who put effort and *volunteer* their time to help moderate the site.

Depends on what they're getting upset with, really.  If they made a mistake *and* they can prove it was a mistake on the volunteers' part, then they'd have a reason to be upset.  However, moderation in general is a pretty thankless job; you're not going to be able to make all of the people happy all of the time.

Comment: You don't get into moderation for thanks and praise, at least that isn't why I got into it.

Answer (score 11):

I think the premise of this question is quite false. It's not "group effort or nothing".

You see, if you compare Stack Overflow to a war (note: I hate bad analogies, but I wanted to use one), most of the actual mess-making action happens on the frontline.

[image: War. It's hell.]

What you see here, left to right:

- Bored users. People who religiously F5 the frontpage and their favorite tag pages. They see the new questions as they arrive, flag them accordingly and throw up their hands in despair after a few minutes per day as to not become entirely crazy.
- Barbed wire. Scripts, tools, algorithms that try to hold back *some* of the cruft that's about to arrive.
- The actual bad guys: users who don't know how to ask a well-formatted, on-topic question. Or poor souls that need to be educated, you pick.
- Cleaners: people who <strike>shovel shit</strike> edit, retag and flag questions that were asked relatively long ago (as in: more than a few hours).

What this last category of users is cleaning up are half-rotten corpses that, when left alone, will be ignored and decompose entirely anyway. Or, so to say, repeatedly bludgeoning a deceased equus.

Whether this effort is the result of a coordinated action or a single misguided soul doesn't matter. What does is: they think they're making the site better, while they should (in my opinion, of course) better be spending their effort at the actual frontline, where the battle is still hot and bloody. Where the user who asked the question is still alive, and not either deserted or shot dead.

Over the course of three weeks, the attention was directed to a thousand-ish very specific, dead, inactive questions, while in the same time [a thousand new questions were asked per *two hours*](https://sostats.github.io/).

So, in short, the problem *I* have with these "burninations" is that I highly doubt their usefulness, and that *I* think that the effort of the people burning these tags is way better spent on new questions as they arrive on the site.

And it doesn't matter at all whether this effort is spent as a group, or by unorganized individuals.

---

As for

> specific posts and comments here to provide evidence that people who choose to close and delete posts do not regularly come under criticism

That's an entirely different discussion altogether, which is about the mentality inside the "clique" chat rooms.

Comment: I would have loved to have this answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process) ...

Comment: @rene well, I don't think I've actually quite seen that question, and as far as that question goes, it looks like _"How do you think the burnination process goes?"_. It goes pretty well I guess, but if you ask _me_, as in this question here, the group effort is _in my opinion_ better spent on issues with ... higher visibility, such as trying to keep the frontpage clean.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. And I think more users agree with you but I have the impression they rather choose to stay silent. If they have an answer with a competing view, like yours, they have at least something to spend their votes on. It might be my way of asking questions that I don't get the answers I want / expect ...

Comment: @rene but then you'll get the chat room to hunt us down! :P

Comment: I was informed there is a hunt going on? *readies pitchfork*

Comment: "half-rotten corpses that, when left alone, will be ignored and decompose entirely anyway" that is mostly a myth. The "decomposer" script is very strict, which means it ends up leaving a lot of stinky rotten corpses behind. So instead of having a nice flower bed after a while, you still have a pile of stinky rotten corpses on your lawn, and off-topic tags attracting new questions. Yes, the front line is an important fight, but it is not the only important fight. Belittling everyone else's fight doesn't solve anything.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with you here in some respects. Some old questions do need to be dealt with. Others, though, have few views and votes -- moderating these are a waste of time, especially considering that [the system could deal with some of these ignored questions automatically](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt).

Comment: "half-rotten corpses that, when left alone, will be ignored and decompose entirely anyway" [the corpses don't necessarily go away](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoBodyLeftBehind), they rot and [release foul odor for years](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+created%3A..1y+score%3A0+answers%3A0+closed%3A0+locked%3A0).

Comment: @Braiam, Tiny, it was a metaphor, not to be taken literally. Like I said, a bad analogy, nothing more. That being said, old questions just _being there_ do less harm than equally bad questions that are on the front page. I'm not belittling anything or anyone, I'm simply stating that **I** find new questions that are on the front page deserving of more attention than older questions.

Comment: But it doesn't read that way... you are saying that those that dedicate time to clean the old are doing the fools errant and should feel bad about it. That you believe the newer deserves more attention doesn't subtract merit of the thankless job they are doing. It's extremely rude to them and their belief.

Comment: @Braiam it is a choice, your choice, to feel offended by words that aren't written. I find it pretty rude of you to project your incorrect interpretation of this answer onto me. I did not write this answer so that the entire SOCVR could come in and fight me. I wrote it to display my opinion: if you have time to spend, you'd better spend it on questions that are now on the frontpage than on those that are asked long ago, hardly ever looked at again and already forgotten. That's my opinion, and you'll have to do with that. Any other interpretation is up to you.

Comment: @Braiam the fact that I didn't start my answer by giving praise to all of those that dedicate their free time to whatever thing they're doing to make the site even a little bit better should not make you read this answer any way different. That praise is implied. Whether you're reviewing, flagging, editing or whatever makes you happy.

Comment: The analogy makes literally no sense to me. The rest of the answer, I 100% agree with. There are two elements here. First is whether it's ever worth it to dredge up old, buried crap when there are so many new questions that need attention (either answered or dispatching). These old questions might be problematic, but they are not hurting anyone by their mere presence. At least, they aren't until you dredge them back up again with a burnination request, which to leads to the more practical problem #2: given the limitations of our tools, tag "burnination" launches a DOS attack on the home page.

Comment: @CodyGray _"The analogy makes literally no sense to me"_ - mission accomplished. :D I just hadn't opened Paint in so long.

Comment: FWIW, I've covered these problems in great detail before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318426/could-we-stop-with-all-those-burnination-requests/318430#318430. The SOVCR chat room mafia or whatever they're calling themselves these days went nuts disagreeing with my answer. For some reason, they take this very personally, much as Yvette's done here. I'm not sure why, this is a very practical issue.

Comment: @Cody I already spent my upvotes on that question, answer and those comments there when they were posted. Couldn't agree more.

Comment: @CodyGray *mafia* whawhawha hahahaha hahaha ...

Comment: I totally agree with this, I asked for am embargo on burninations. I think tags should just be retired, so they cannot be used anymore. And leave it all. The thing that sh!ts me the most, is that godaddy burn post is one of the highest upvoted questions here and who helped?  Also, love the art work.

Comment: @CodyGray I asked for an embargo on burninations. I hate them. I left the socvr team because I find it's exhausting and impossible to try and get on top of the close vote queue, particularly when there's posts being bumped in there that shouldn't be there. I helped with the godaddy burnination, as I feel sorry for people trying to do it, It's the last time. The thing is that godaddy burn request is one of the highest voted Qs on meta. It's insane. Sometimes I think the whims of this community are insane. They don't really know what they want, because when they get it they complain.

Comment: Well, you are putting a lot of stock in the voting on Meta, @Yvette. It is not entirely clear what a vote means here, as we so often point out to others. Does a vote on a burnination request actually mean, *"Yes, I agree this burnination should be done. I fully support it."*, or does it mean *"This is an interesting idea, we should consider it"*, or maybe it just means *"This is a well-written proposal"*. Also, I've said this before, but I think the real problem is the *process*. Some people are against deletion altogether, but most aren't. They just don't like how disruptive burnination is.

Comment: I couldn't resist but notice the similarity between your 4 bullets and the [4 camps of hate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/922184) that I posted 2 years ago. (Bored Users = camp 3 repwhores, actual bad guys = camp 2 help-vampires, cleaners = camp 1 caretakers) The only one that doesn't match is barbed-wire and camp 4/apathetics. If this was unintentional, then clearly there's some truth to my post if others are independently coming to the same conclusion - albeit with alternate ways to describe it.

Comment: What's missing from your analogy is the notion of a *force multiplier*: a group, tool or process that exists to make the folks on the "front line" more effective. In an actual army, that includes things like more effective weaponry, supply lines, intelligence and other support staff - ultimately, the products of a huge number of people who *aren't fighting* but whose efforts enable those who are to be successful (and amusingly, the sorts of bureaucracy that are often seen as useless overhead in other organizations). Not just barbed wire. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175

Comment: @CodyGray I see what you're saying about voting, but if that premise is true, then there's entirely no point in using votes to achieve anything.

Answer (score 4):

> What good (if any) do these groups really achieve for the site? Are
>   they more problem than help?

They do a lot of good. They mean thousands of valid closings and retagging and editing of content which would not happen, would users not coordinate themselves and use synergies to moderate the content more efficiently.

**Please, please continue to do so!!** Don't get distracted by the criticism, every action always gets criticized by someone. This doesn't mean much. Just stay cool and follow the usual procedure.

The effective benefits for the content is huuuuge.

However, there are two things to keep in mind:

- For the people taking part in the coordinated effort: This can be very demanding. **Please watch out for burnout signs on yourself (like you are easily annoyed or feel like it is a lot of work..)!** In the end it's more useful for the site if you contribute to moderation on a stable level.
- Coordinated efforts inherently have the risk to create correlated behavior. So if something goes wrong, it could go even more wrong than usual. A wrong decision can be amplified. Usually we require five independent votes for closing. I would dispute that coming from a coordinated effort like sovcr they are completely independent. So maybe five votes from there do not carry exactly the same decision power like five votes coming from everywhere. This is not critical and probably only a minor effect but it means **we probably should remain somewhat critical on coordinated efforts, despite the on average overwhelming positive effect.** If they go wrong, they could go wrong more pronouncedly. In the end I guess, meta discussions will be used to coordinate and correct the coordinated efforts.

Comment: I really like this answer, I think it's my favourite, it's balanced.

Comment: @Yvette Thanks. Be careful with yourself and avoid burnout, you seem to do a lot.

Answer (score -1):

No, Stack Overflow doesn't *need* coordinated moderation.  [I am not arguing that it is right, wrong, good, bad, or guy with the gun, but that it is just ... *unnecessary*.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330059/3614835)  Stack Overflow will keep working pretty much as well as it has if you decide you're done seeking out trouble.

You're not obligated.

Comment: *Stack Overflow will keep working pretty much as well as it has if you decide you're done seeking out trouble.* pretty rude

Comment: I don't know what that link has to do with the post, but I'm glad you put it in. I completely agree with it's sentiments ;)

Comment: that's ok if you didn't intend to be rude, I read it personally

Comment: ah yeh, I see the line now. I got distracted by the content. Yes a good link.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to say you specifically are unnecessary; I mean that none of us are obligated to seek out stuff to clean up.  I can't come up with a more-obviously-impersonal phrasing that isn't so wordy as to be unclear, though.

Comment: It's all good, thanks for that clarification.

Comment: I personally hate the use of 'one' as a pronoun in English, but this is one of those cases where if you mentally `s/you/one/g` it's a little clearer what the author intended and more difficult to personalize.

Comment: I think unnecessary is the wrong word here. "Not required" seems to be what you intend to say.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yes I think the english language is lacking with the use of 'one' and also, there's 'they' to represent a single person. Both don't sit well, but are sometimes preferable.