# What is the appropriate reaction to meta tags?

Tags: discussion, edits, meta-tags

The fundamental doctrine is already laid out in [*The Death of Meta Tags*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) — as I've seen referenced many, many times — but I found no guidance on how to react to meta tags (when applied to a particular question, but also generally).  The only examples I see are specific questions for each possible meta tag.  Is that still the best approach?  Should I edit a question just to remove a meta tag?  Or should I just shrug and move on?

UPDATE:  Realized during discussion in the comments, the larger question is "In the overall 'burnination process' for meta tags, what role do general Stack Overflow users (including low rep users) have in identifying and removing meta tags?"

Comment: I vote for either "disgust" or "surprise".

Comment: *just* to remove a meta tag? Likely it's best to move on. If there are other things you can edit in the question as well, edit all the things. Make sure you leave a good edit summary so reviewers know why you made the edit.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  Even before posting I wondered if it was just a silly question since I'd probably do just what you suggest.  But "Death" is a strong word and I repeatedly see references to the blog post in other meta questions, and it seems like more than any other single blog or help article.  I get the impression it is a "serious" matter for keeping SO uncluttered and useful.  Many aspects of SO are open to community edits and upkeep, so is this to suggest that meta tag matters should just be left to the high-ranking users or SO developers only?

Comment: Not necessarily. The thing is, when you have less than 2k rep, your edits have to go through the suggested edit review queue, meaning a bunch of people have to look at it and take their time to ensure a good edit. I don't like wasting people's time, so making sure an edit encompasses as many of the necessary changes as possible is a Good Thing to me. Others have expressed disagreement with that, so take it for what it's worth. We also have a "burnination process" by which we take tags like that and get rid of them in an orderly manner.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  Advise noted on edit reviews, but now we're getting to the point of my question... what is the "burniation process"?  Who is "We", the +2k rep users?   And how do you decide what tags are considered for burniation?  Is there nothing that us low rep folks can do to contribute to keeping SO nice and tidy?

Answer (score 12):

If the tag is used on a significant number of questions, then you need to raise a Meta question about it. A "punny" title is <strike>essential</strike> optional, but it needs to include the name of the tag and a list of reasons why you think the tag is problematic. The community will then vote on this question, and possibly post answers, indicating whether or not they agree with your assessment. You need to give this process *time* to occur, as not everyone with relevant opinions monitors Meta 24/7. If sufficient time has gone by (say, a week?) and you've garnered a consensus, then you can move on to the next steps in [the burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

(But, beware the problems with the "burnination" system, covered in detail [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318426/could-we-stop-with-all-those-burnination-requests/318430#318430). The question you really need to ask yourself that so often gets missed is, "Is this tag hurting anything?" and "Is this a good use of our time and the disruption that it will introduce actually worth it?" If the answer to those questions is "no", then you should probably reconsider. If there were a better way to burninate that was lower-impact, then I might change my mind about this, but the developers don't seem interested in fixing this problem, so reality takes precedence for me over an abstract and ideal "purity" of the tag system. Some "meta" tags *are* harmful, though, like [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework), and it made good sense for us to burninate that one.)

If you come across a Stupid Tag™ that's only been used on a couple of questions, then you can just go ahead and remove it yourself. However, you should make sure that you fix any other problems with the question while you're editing, *especially* if you do not have full editing privileges (and thus your edits require community approval). This maximizes the impact and decreases the amount of time wasted for all parties.

Comment: Punny titles are optional? What is this heresy of which you speak my good sir? /s

Comment: Ponny titles are better.

Comment: In summary, meta tags are sentenced to death by mob to the guillotine rather than secret tribunal.  A beautiful example of pure democracy on July 4th.

Comment: @CPerkins More like either 1). Hanging, drawing, and quartering, or 2). Burning at the stake. There's isn't much about the process that is quick and painless like a guillotine.

Comment: @TinyGiant so perhaps [cutting the heart out with a spoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhfuuKiTcYQ)? Involving for all parties involved.

Comment: I will note that a de-bodied head still maintains consciousness for upwards of twenty seconds.

Comment: How did the comments turn dark so quickly? This is the type of lynch-mob mentality that worries me already about Meta "burninate" requests.