# Should we allow questions to be tagged [advent-of-code]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

I noticed today that questions are being edited to add [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code), which to me seems to be a meta-tag that doesn't belong on Stack Overflow as it doesn't help classify the actual question (IMHO). I started rolling back some of those edits, but given the volume of tagged questions, I don't think I should make this decision unilaterally.

So, I'm looking for consensus: should this tag be allowed, and if not should we burninate and maybe blacklist it?

Comment: Related: [What is the appropriate reaction to meta tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351636/1426539)

Comment: I think we should treat this tag like other coding challenges tags.

Comment: There seems to be mostly a single user spamming this tag all around.

Comment: Similar to [Burninate Project Euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275935/2821954), this may also be burninated.

Comment: Didn't know about the convention on meta-tags. Just found a question that quite clearly references the Advent of Code and didn't find a corresponding tag yet. I thought adding the tag would make it easier for contestants to find alternative solutions.

Comment: It seems like the user (oh, just noticed you responded at the same time as me, Endzeit, apologies) was burning the [tag:aoc] but introducing the equally problematic (semantically) tag (from the standpoint of not describing what the question is about according to the scope of SO). Looks like it does need to be burned as a meta tag - if somebody cares to make a burnination request, it will be nice - I have a suspicion questions under this tag need some culling too

Comment: @OlegValter What do you think, should I just add tag burninate-request, or does this require more?

Comment: I think @Endzeit should put things back the way they were i.e. revert those tag edits.

Comment: @Endzeit nothing wrong with trying to fix tagging, but code challenges are not on topic on SO unless the question is really about a specific programming problem and not asking for an alternative solution (optimization of working code goes on Code Review, puzzles - on Code Golf, etc) which makes he tag "meta" as ot does not describe what the question really asks. I would link to the guidelines on that matter, but I am on mobile right now, and it is a chore to do so from it - I am sure other responders will, though (and urge them to do so)

Comment: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/11682469)

Comment: @Mark well, there are quite a few questions with the tag, so the proper procedure requires a burnination request, but I am not sure if it can't be foregone here as the tag falls under the same category as other code challenge tags which have a consensus that they need to be burned [sending smoke signals to Jeanne to find the post if possible]. Simply reverting will likely not do as [aoc] should equally be removed, so we can all proceed chipping away at the tag until it is gone, then wait the for it to be auto-removed

Comment: @OlegValter You mean the question linked by Andrew T ([Burninate Project Euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler))

Comment: @OlegValter *"well, there are quite a few questions with the tag"* - Only because one person just added them all...

Comment: @Endzeit, when reverting edits, you might want to use the rollback instead of doing a reverse edit. Not sure if it matters much, but at least it seems to describe the revision history better, IMHO.

Comment: Regarding the tag, I don't think it will add much, because when looking for solutions, you might as well search on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=advent+of+code). Unless the question is specifically about the underlying programming problem, in which case the advent-of-code tag on Stack Overflow is not relevant.

Comment: @Zoe does this mean its burninated or blacklisted?

Comment: @SurajRao burned for now, I have no idea how to blacklist anyway

Comment: @Nick ah, even easier then :) seems like the problem's solved now

Comment: What is it? Is it *[Advent of Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_of_Code)*? - *"Advent of Code is an annual set of Christmas-themed computer programming challenges that follow an Advent calendar and can be solved using any programming language."*. Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess it is.

Comment: I don't think having it as a tag is very useful. Everyone's doing the challenges with different languages etc, and I don't think anyone's going to be more of an expert on advent of code regardless of language than they are on their language regardless of what's being done. At that point they might as well tag it as a logic puzzle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both [Endzeit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160089/endzeit) and [Zoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe) have edited the questions to remove the tag again, so the problem is gone.