# The [adventofcode] just started - Stop it before it gets out of hand

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

I saw [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) had been created where essentially the same tag ([advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code)) [has been removed from the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413443/10871900) last year.

While I removed [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) from the questions associated with it, this won't last as people will likely use this tag until it is removed (it requires there are no questions in the tag when the tag cleanup script is run once during the UTC day).

I propose to blocklist both [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) and [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code), so these tags can not be added to questions, preventing these tags from being recreated again.

I propose the following error message:

> While questions about the algorithms in Advent of Code might be on-topic on Stack Overflow, the event itself is not. Instead of using this tag, please include the tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: Should we include the common abbreviation `aoc` as well?

Comment: @AnonCoward: Has anyone created or attempted to create that as a tag? If not, then I don't see a need for `aoc` to be a blocked tag.

Comment: @V2Blast Fair enough, I'm mostly thinking of people trying to "work around" a limitation, though in practice that's probably not a thing

Comment: @V2Blast Not yet anyway, but we can just revisit it if the [adventofcode] and [advent-of-code] blacklisting results in [aoc] being created

Comment: Please, for the love of my god, no aoc!

Comment: @MartinJames let's leave [US politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandria_Ocasio-Cortez) out of it :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've added a block on [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code) and [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode). Both use the text:

> While questions about the algorithms used in Advent of Code might be on-topic on Stack Overflow, you do not need to tag these questions to indicate their origin. Please include the tag for the programming language you are using instead.

You might have to wait a moment for the next deploy in order for these to take effect. Thanks to a fast response from the dev team on this one!

Answer (score 14):

Moderators can help this situation, but can't actually *resolve* it.

I've "merged" [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) into [blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective) (effectively renaming it). What this does is renames the tag the system thinks is "undeleted" to "blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective" and marks [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) as "deleted" again. Thus, [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) will, once again, require >= 1,500 reputation to "create". That won't prevent a user with >= 1,500 reputation from creating it, but it will prevent it from being added to questions by users with < 1,500 reputation and require users with >= 1,500 reputation to explicitly confirm the creation.

The [blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective) tag name contains the text "subjective", which is blocklisted anywhere in a tag, so the tag can't be added to a question. The system should delete [blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective) within the next 24 hours.

I've also created synonyms from [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) and [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code) to [blocked-tag-do-not-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-do-not-use), which doesn't exist. So, while the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) will show that [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) and [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code) exist, user's with < 1,500 reputation won't be able to add them to a question. Users with >= 1,500 reputation will be able to *try* to add those tags, but they will be asked if they want to create [blocked-tag-do-not-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-do-not-use) and that's the tag which will be added to the question, if they create it.

As I said at the top of this answer, these actions don't *actually* resolve the problem of [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) and [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code) being able to be created, but the actions will A) make the system such that user's with < 1,500 reputation can't use those tags (at lest for now); and B) should make it clear to anyone with >= 1,500 reputation who does try to create either of them that they shouldn't have done so, because the tag which will be displayed will be [blocked-tag-do-not-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-do-not-use).

---

Note: The above would be more complex if there were any deleted questions with the tags which we were trying to prevent from being used. If there were deleted questions, then any synonym-target should be one which uniquely identifies the original tag name, so that we can retain the information as to what the original name was for the tag. In this case, there were no deleted questions with either [adventofcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventofcode) or [advent-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advent-of-code), so generic targets are probably reasonable. We may want to revisit that, if it ends up we see [blocked-tag-do-not-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-do-not-use) created.

---

Unfortunately, the system doesn't permit creating synonyms to tags that are *actually* blocked, so the synonym target can't be [blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tag-dont-use-subjective). I also tried creating a synonym to a test tag and then renaming the test tag to a name that's blocked. In that case, while the list of synonyms shows the correctly renamed tag as the target, when actually trying to add the synonym to a question, the system uses the synonym target as it was prior to the rename. So, that attempted workaround is ineffective.